# Symfony: how to redistribute a private bundle between different projects

Tags: git, symfony

Let's say the symfony project a contains a bundle called `MyCompany/MyBundle` in the root folder of the project.

As this bundle is some kind of standard software for all my projects, I want to share them easily and copy it to project b, c, ...

What is the best way to sync this (private) Bundle?

- Copy paste between project folders as needed
- Using git and e.g. github and composer*
- something better :)
- ...

**Problems with Git/Composer solution: This would need two repos, one for the project and one for the Bundle, but the Bundle is within the project. Moreover composer would download it to `vendor` on the other projects and not the root folder)*

Comment: I would make separate the bundle as a separate Git repository and then just include it via composer.  As long as your namespaces are all set up properly this should work just fine.

Comment: @JasonRoman But as I'm developing I would need to change between Project a and MyBundle constantly, which would cost a lot of time as I'd have to test MyBundle, commit and push it, then update composer and Project a and implement the changes. This would be only one step if MyBundle lives within Project a (say: my master project on which I develop and test most of my software).

Comment: Yes, that definitely can become a hassle, having to constantly run `composer update` on all projects that use that bundle.  But it ensures consistency and you're not duplicating copy/pasted code across project, which takes even longer.  You could even internally write scripts to do `composer update` whenever you commit to your standard bundle.  Another option is to just have one giant project that contains all of your sub-projects.

Comment: @JasonRoman what about Git submodules?

Comment: I haven't dealt with those so I can't offer you any advice there

Comment: @Petermeir git submodules won't do magic for you. It is just one of the styles of storing part of the source code.

Answer (score 1):

> > As this bundle is some kind of standard software for all my projects ...

In such case, you should extract it into a stand-alone bundle so that you can include it in composer.json of your projects. You can then see your bundle in `vendor/...` folder.

If your bundle doesn't depend on any parameter coming from main projects, you can see how it is done here [Creating a simple symfony vendor bundle to use it in a main project](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/qey0/creating-a-simple-symfony-vendor-bundle-to-use-it-in-a-main-project).

If your bundle does depend on parameter(s) coming from main projects, you can see how it is done here: [Creating an encrypt-decrypt symfony bundle that depends on config parameters of main application](http://www.inanzzz.com/index.php/post/rxqs/creating-an-encrypt-decrypt-symfony-bundle-that-depends-on-config-parameters-of-main-application)

Regarding to your concerns about time it takes to update projects, you shouldn't worry about it because:

- It wouldn't take more than 2 minutes to update bundle on given project.
- Like @Jason Roman said, you get consistency otherwise highly likely you might do things differently in some projects. Trust me, it happens!
- You want to do know the "`...best way to sync bundle`".

Answer (score 1):

There is a second approach which comes in handy when the shared bundle is still under heavy development.  Something like:

```
projects
    shared\src\MyBundle
    project1
    project2
    etc
```

Edit projectx\app\autoload.php and add a path to your shared bundle src so everyone can find the shared code.  Something like:

```
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
$loader->add('MyBundle',   __DIR__  . '/../../shared/src');
```

Now changes made to MyBundle will be automatically accessed by the other projects.

Eventually when the shared bundle is stabilized, you can turn it into a package and use composer to install into vendor.  But during development, this approach works well for me.